Order of connection using digital multimeter wall outlet
It seems common knowledge among electricians that when measuring voltage across a battery, one must connect the black probe first (ground) and the red one second for safety reasons primarily.
My question is: does this order matter in an AC circuit such as a wall outlet?

This question is rather subjective. Order doesn't matter whether you're measuring a battery or a wall outlet. But in both cases, I would probably still use similar safety precautions... especially since a wall outlet is potentially more lethal than a battery.

You could read the voltmeter manual for safety advice, but I've never seen any requirements on order of connection for any voltage measurement instrument DC or AC.  You can hook up the voltmeter probes backward too, and still gives a valid reading.

Put the safety glasses on first?

If you don't have a properly rated and fused multimeter and know how to use it, don't connect it to the mains at all.

Connect the neutral first.  That way the unconnected probe will have less chance of being hot.

Many multimeters can also be configured to measure current. How many of us have erroneously meant to measure voltage, while configured to measure current? Very dangerous. After the first probe is connected to neutral (doesn't matter whether red or black), the second probe won't be potentially lethal to the user. jsotola gives good advice, but, sniff, poor multimeter will suffer regardless from this mistake once second probe is connected.

@glen_geek This should not happens. Even if you set your multimeter selector to "current" when you want to measure a voltage and plug it to the main, nothing happens. One probe has to be plugged into the "A" socket of the multimeter to create a short with the other probe. If it is still on the "V" socket, nothing happens, regardless of the selector position

@Blup1980 As you've pointed out, MANY multimeter-makers force users to swap leads between two jacks dedicated to "volts,ohms" or to "amps" as a safety measure. Nevertheless, some users forget to swap (to their peril)...I've seen it often. May we survive, so that a hard lesson is learned. Fuses are rated to protect multimeter internal parts, not the user (from touching the tip of a probe whose mate connects to "hot" rather than "neutral", while erroneously configured for current).

@Blup1980, my multimeter uses one socket for voltage, resistance, … measurements and current measurements in low ranges. Only for the 10 A range, the other socket is used. Not all manufacturers choose to provide better safety.


My question is: does this order matter in an AC circuit such as a wall outlet?

Where possible, it is best practice to connect the "less dangerous" terminal first and disconnect it last. This reduces the risk from accidents while one probe is connected and the other is not. Specifically "Accidents" here could mean at least two things.

Touching the disconnected probe to your body or some other item. The input resistance of the meter will limit the current, but it's still not an ideal situation.
accidentally moving the connected probe and shorting something out with it. In this case there is no current limiting, so it's probablly the bigger risk. Especially if you are using probes with a lot of exposed metal.

In mains wiring.

Ground/Earth is the safest terminal.
Hot/Live/Phase is the most dangerous terminal.
Neutral is between the two, it's normally referenced to earth but broken wires and reverse polarity are risks that should be considered*.

Sometimes, both terminals are dangerouns

It seems common knowledge among electricians that when measuring voltage across a battery, one must connect the black probe first (ground) and the red one second for safety reasons primarily.

When testing a battery that is not installed in anything it doesn't matter, both terminals are generally equally safe.
When testing a battery installed in a car, the terminal connected to the car's chassis is safer. In modern cars that is usually the negative terminal (known as a "negative earth" configuration), but there are some historic cars with a "positive earth" configuration still in operation. Telephone exchanges also traditionally used 48V supplies with a positive earth configuration.
* Depending on the details of the supply you are working with, and the regulatory environment in which you are working it may or may not be acceptable to work on wiring with the Neutral still connected.

Copper wires which are positively biased relative to any moisture that is in contact with them will disperse copper ions into that moisture.  Those which are biased negative will grab ions from that moisture.  Given how thin phone wires are, the latter is preferable.

Your first misunderstanding is, when measuring a battery, it does not matter in any way if you connect black or red first. When measuring voltages in a device (like on a pcb), it is helpful to connect first to the ground plane since it is easier to hit (larger area of contact compared to some sub-mm lead of an IC) and you might do multiple measurements with the same ground reference, so the black lead stays in place while the red might move.
From an electrical perspective, it does not matter at all.
When measuring an AC voltage, what differs the "phase" from "neutral" is the potential with respect to ground.
One could make a point that it might be a tad safer to connect neutral first so the dangling other cord will be at ground potential.
However, a multimeter is generally the wrong device for that and such measurements should use a voltage tester like they are available from bands like Duspol or Fluke, among others.
They are specifically designed to provide a safe way for handling mains voltages, and you want a quality device when you are potentially trusting your life on it. E.g. a multimeter might often read voltages even on disconnected wires due to stray inductance.

I will grant that a multimeter poses a danger if set to a measurement other than voltage, and one probe is connected to line and the other open. However, in what other way would a (measuring, not non-contact) voltage tester be different from a multimeter? Good practice with a multimeter is to always set switch to voltage before attempting a voltage measurement.

@MathKeepsMeBusy - and yet for zero voltage verification you need to use an honest to goodness multimeter, and that multimeter must be used before and after ZVV to measure a live outlet. Multimeters, properly used, are a perfectly good device for measuring voltages.

"a multimeter might often read voltages even on disconnected wires due to stray inductance." The LoZ setting on my Fluke shows that's it's made for measuring utility levels of voltage. A multimeter is the proper device to measure voltage, but not to measure line levels of current. A clamp meter is the proper device for current, as it works across insulation.

Most clamp meters also have a set of probes for voltage, resistance and sometimes even capaitance ranges, while lacking the risky wired current range. If buying a meter specifically for mains electrical work I would recommend a clamp meter over a regular multimeter.
